# Collapse event doesn't work in angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've recently got stuck with such a problem.
I use [angular-ui bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) and I want to call `show.bs.collapse` callback for collapse, but nothing happens. Here's my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rD1w7lqdBgJjAuGGEfQE?p=preview) .

Comment: @Alessio I'll be grateful if you could give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watch

```
  $scope.$watch('isCollapsed', function(isCollapsed){
    if(isCollapsed){
      alert("BOL"); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it will work by just pressing the button, I need the event to work after show/hide collapse. [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rD1w7lqdBgJjAuGGEfQE?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah, I saw this issue, but yet didn't understand how to use it